# Render image rendering incorrectly with a checkered pattern

Tags: rendering, materials

I am learning Blender and following some Udemy courses. I added some materials to the model and in the render viewport, it looks completely fine in that nothing looks broken.
[image]

When I add a camera to the scene and try take a render image, it's almost like the materials are missing and it comes out all spotted and checkered looking.
[image]

Does anyone have an idea what might be causing that to happen?

Comment: Hello :). These look like overlapping faces. Perhaps you have another (same) mesh only visible in renders.

Comment: Oh goodness, I hate being beginner at things lol, that was exactly it, I didn't even think of that. I had a backup model disabled in the viewport but not in the render. Thank you @JachymMichal

Comment: Happens all the time :). Glad you made it work.

Answer (score 1):

What @Jachym Michal said is correct. Press ALT H in the viewport, your second object should appear, otherwise search in the outliner. 
 Btw. this irregular pattern of triangles and weird stripes is called z-fighting, where z is the distance to the camera, it means 2 faces occupy the same space and the camera has troubles deciding which one to show in each sample.